# How to retrieve data from database and display in textview or toast or in alerts anything?

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

```
public class SearchActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
EditText recupdate;
Button update;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_search);

    recupdate = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtusername);
    update = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnupdate);
    update.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view){

            SQLiteDatabase fuuast = openOrCreateDatabase("MyDb", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
            fuuast.execSQL("Create table if not exists std_rec(username varchar primary key, password varchar, age Integer, phone Integer)  ");
            String query = "Select * from std_rec Where username = '"+update.getText()+"'";
            fuuast.execSQL(query);


            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            startActivity(i);
        }

    });
}
```

how to show data or where to show please help i want to show data after clicking on search button sorry for my English i am ab beginner

Comment: Where do you want to show the data?could you elaborate?

Comment: anywhere on same activity or alert or pop ups or textview

Comment: check the answer below @AdilKhan

Answer (score -1):

Make cursor with query which will have your data

```
SQLiteDatabase db = openOrCreateDatabase("MyDb", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM std_rec";

Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
if(cursor != null) {
    cursor.moveToFirst();   
    startManagingCursor(cursor);
    for (int i = 0; i < cursor.getCount(); i++) {
        String message = cursor.getString(0);
        // Here display message as you like, in toast, alert or TextView
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Remove that line and try again.

Comment: Best solution would be to make SQLitehelperClass that extends SQLiteOpenHelper

Comment: I did not downvote. But in my experience some people downvote simply for giving an answer to a downvoted question, no matter how good the answer is. They probably hate the idea that somebody gets a badge for giving a good answer to a bad question, there is one. Be happy, try to get that badge and beat me to it. Also in my experience, fast-downvoters never bother to check on the question/answer they downvoted and therefor ignore any polite requests for explanation. (Your answer is beyond me by the way, so excuse me for not upvoting.)

Comment: @Yunnosch it doesn't matter if my points are decreased because of it, I only want the reason for it, if my answer is wrong then he/she should correct my answer, at least give some reason for down voting, thats very unethical or unprofessional .

Comment: @AbdulKawee where to display output?